# "No resource found that matches given name" for a resource I'm not using

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the message:

```
Error:(282, 50) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:titleTextAppearance' with value '@style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Title').
```

however, I'm not trying to access the resource in my styles or anywhere else. I was trying to access it in a style recently but I deleted it already.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow Android Studio generated a second values folder called values-v21 with styles.xml under it containing a reference to android:titleTextAppearance. I was able to correct this by correcting the style in the styles.xml file under values-v21.

Comment: "somehow"? That folder is generated for a reason - to have specific resources on API 21+. You  should only delete the folder if you know you don't need them